# How to access nodemon log on running docker container

Tags: docker, nodemon

I've got a node docker container that starts my app with nodemon.

What I would like to do, is access that container and somehow view nodemon console log.

I can access the container shell with `docker exec -ti <container id> bash`, `ps aux` tells me that nodemon is running my app, but I couldn't find any documentation about accessing the output of nodemon while it's running.

Should I forward output to a file when starting nodemon or should the log be accessible in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `docker logs -f cid`. This fill give you system output and system error streams from the container `cid`